# Find the formula for the volume of solids congruent to this one rotated about the x axis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am working through some examples in my multivariate calculus workbook, and I am unsure of how to proceed with this one.
I am asked to find the volume of a solid similar to the one in the below graph, but with dimensions r and s instead of 3 and 2 respectively, obtained by rotating the following region about the x axis:
[image]

I cannot figure out how to compute this.

If someone wouldnt mind lending a few pointers, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Harish has answered this completely. However I suggest that you see and read animations about calculating volume by integration. There is enough material out there and will be of great benefit in the long run

Answer (score 1):

The figure consists of straight line & the arc of circle.

The volume of the solid generated by rotating straight line: $y=\frac{s}{r}x$ about the x-axis $$V_1=\int_{0}^{r}\pi y^2dx=\int_{0}^{r}\pi\left(\frac{s}{r}x\right)^2dx$$ $$=\frac{\pi s^2}{r^2}\int_{0}^{r}x^2 dx=\frac{\pi s^2}{r^2}\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{0}^{r}=\frac{\pi s^2}{r^2}\left[\frac{r^3}{3}\right]$$  $$=\frac{1}{3}\pi rs^2$$

The volume of the solid generated by rotating arc of circle: $(x-r)^2+y^2=s^2$ about the x-axis $$V_2=\int_{r}^{r+s}\pi y^2dx=\int_{r}^{r+s}\pi(s^2-\left(x-r\right)^2)dx$$
$$=\pi\int_{r}^{r+s}s^2-\left(x-r\right)^2dx=\pi \left[s^2 x-\frac{(x-r)^3}{3}\right]_{r}^{r+s}=\frac{\pi s^2}{r^2}\left[s^2(r+s)-\frac{s^3}{3}-s^2(r)+0\right]$$  $$=\pi \left[\frac{2 s^3}{3}\right]$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\pi s^3$$

Hence, the volume of the complete solid generated by rotation about the x-axis $$=V_1+V_2$$$$=\frac{1}{3}\pi rs^2+\frac{2}{3}\pi s^3$$ $$=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{3}\pi (r+2s)s^2}$$